# Neo4j subscribe to DB changes in Python

Tags: database, neo4j, microservices

There are 2 microservices, one inserts data into the database using a queue of entries and the other one makes some complicated calculations and creates relations between nodes based on this calculation.

Instead of calling the second microservice in the first one using a REST API, websocket etc., I want to just subscribe to db changes in the second microservice. Is there a plugin, library etc. to subscribe neo4j db changes in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j Streams features Change Data Capture feature that streams db changes to Kafka. https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/4.0/producer/. If you don't want to use Kafka, you have the option to use APOC triggers, but they are not as mature as kafka IMO. https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/background-operations/triggers/. However, you have the option to be very specific which changes do you want to listen for.  Here's one example that does a request upon a trigger, but you would probably send a POST request somewhere: https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/03/07/neo4j-apoc-triggers-and-web-apis/

Comment: So there is no way to listen for db changes using only a driver or a plugin. If I'm not mistaken APOC triggers only allows to run another db operation, meaning that we can't run a python script upon a db change, which is what I needed. Probably I'll have an mqtt client in both of my microservices for another reason, so I'll use the mqtt protocol to notify the second microservice. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can use apoc.load.json procedure to send a request with APOC triggers, it is not limited to db updates FYI. But I wouldnt use them in production anyway